# rails 4 show error message validations in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, form-for

Hi I have nested resource:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :msgs
end
```

and some validations:

```
class Msg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates :body ,presence:true
end
```

a controller:

```
# msgs_controller.erb
def create
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @msg=@post.msgs.build(msg_params)
 @msg.user=current_user
 @msg.email=current_user.email
 @msg.autor=current_user.name

 if @msg.save
   flash[:notice] = t '.create'
 end
 respond_with(@post,@msg)
end
```

and a view:
    EDIIT: /views/posts/show.html.rb
    # /views/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.msgs.build]) do |f| %>

    <% if @msg.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">

          <h2><%= pluralize(@msg.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this msg from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @msg.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>


    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

the app doesn't shows the errors messages when body field is blank, but the validations are ok becouse the server show me ROLLBACK instead COMMIT. The problem is to show the error messages in the views, can you help me?

Comment: Is there anything at all in `@msg.errors`? What does the data in `@msg` actually look like at the point when you're trying to save?  You mention that it is doing a ROLLBACK, but if the validation is really failing it would not try to do an INSERT at all. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence - section 1.2, second paragraph.  This indicates that maybe validations are not actually failing and something else is going wrong with the save (causing the ROLLBACK).

Comment: Does your `Posts` model have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :msg`? If so, I'm wondering if the errors would show up in `@post.errors` instead. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: i have try to eliminate the validation in the msg model and the blanck comment is committed in the db. With the validation active the blanck comment is not committed but is rollbacked. I have seen this in server's log and throught database query.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article on how to do flash messages the Rails 4 way: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/register-your-own-flash-types-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

From the article:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
    ...
  add_flash_types :error, :another_custom_type
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    redirect_to home_path,
      error: "An error message for the user"
  end
end

# app/views/home/index
<%= error %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form should be in the `new` and not in the `show` view. Then, you can render the page if not saved to display the error.

```
....
 if @msg.save
   flash[:notice] = t '.create'
 else
   render 'new'
 end
....
```

Comment: yes according whit this article http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering the respond_with method respond with new if the form has errors. So i have created a new view for the msg and now the form redirects here (if there's error) else the form redirect to the show of the post resource.

Comment: in your question the form appears in the `show` view, and not in the `new` as recommended. If you look at the article you will see that the `create` has a `if` and a `else` conditions. The `else` (if not saved) must RENDER the form and then the `@msg.errors.any?` will be `true` and the error will be displayed. If you use REDIRECT when not saved, you won't have the `@msg.errors`....

Comment: ok thanks, now i have completly understand the behavior. My problem is i should to redirect with the errors not in the :new but in the show..